# How can I Customize URL Created using createObjectURL,

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to create a pdf document and i would like to open it without showing download window, I used `a.download` so that currently its displaying download dialog to avoid that i tried it without `a.download` but the url looks like `blob:https://localhost/6767676-d5d5f-4150-85bf-456333bebd17` but How can i customize to display as `https://localhost/productNumber.pdf` instead

```
      $.ajax({
                url: '/product/product/CreateSOEntryLine',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    var formData = new URLSearchParams();
                        formData.set("productID", data.productID);
                       
                         request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
                                var a = document.createElement('a');

                                var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(request.response);

                                    a.href = fileURL;
                                    a.download = `${data.productNumber}.pdf`;// without this line automatically open in a new tab thats what i want but i need to customize url as https://localhost/productNumber.pdf

                                    a.style.display = 'none';
                                    a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                                    document.body.appendChild(a);

                                    a.click();
                            }
                        };

                    var url = `@(Url.Action("createPDF", "product", new { Area = "product" }))?` + formData.toString();
                    request.open("GET", url);
                    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    request.responseType = 'blob';
                    request.send();
                }
            })
```

currently the url looks like `blob:https://localhost/6767676-d5d5f-4150-85bf-45787898ebd17` but i would like to see `https://localhost/productNumber.pdf`

Comment: Use javascript history push state api.

Comment: Why are you using `XMLHttpRequest` inside an $.ajax success function? Anyway, create a server-side API that detects a GET request for `/productNumber.pdf` and serves the file. Then use that as URL. One way to do that is url rewriting, but it depends on the server you're using. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0